# How to get Request.UrlReferrer and ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] wich are both NULL. Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple form with Post request to page. When user clicks the subscribe button he comes to the page, where I would like to have information about where it come from. I have tested it using small site, to make sure I have redirect..

**Request.UrlReferrer and ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] is NULL**

IP and all other data is in place.

*How do i find the Url, Form was posted to my page from ?*

Form designed to be embedded on any site/page with simply copy/paste.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307070/php-http-referrer) has reported that HTTP_REFERER doesn't get populated in posts across domains.

So I think it would be better to rely on JavaScript to populate a hidden input in your form with the referring page just before submission. Something like this:

```
<form action="http://www.yourdomain.com/subscribe" 
   method="POST" 
   onsubmit=
      "document.getElementById('www.yourdomain.com.referrer').value=window.location;" >
    <!-- hidden input for field starts with a domain registered by you 
    just so that it's unlikely to clash with anything else on the page -->
    <input type="hidden" id="www.yourdomain.com.referrer" name="referrer"/>
    your email: <input name="email" type="text"/>
    ... rest of form ...
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

Then you can get the referring URL from Request.Form["referrer"] in the handling page.