# How to get, in which page i posted my data in php?

Tags: php, post, httprequest, http-host

How do I get, from which page/url the data in the $_POST variable come from :`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP HTTP Referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307070/php-http-referrer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Answer (score -1):

The super-global [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) could be useful for you, specifically `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SERVER);

//    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => 
//    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 
//    [REMOTE_PORT] => 
//    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => 
//    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => 
//    [SERVER_NAME] => 
//    [SERVER_PORT] => 
//    [REQUEST_URI] => /f1 <-----------------
//    ...
```